# How to map OneToMany within a table?

Tags: wordpress, hibernate, jpa

o-o!

I am trying to map the wp_posts table from WordPress database. I have left out information to simplify my question:

This is the entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wp_posts")
@Getter
@Setter
public class WPPosts {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "post_parent")
    private long postParent;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = WPPosts.class, mappedBy = "postParent")
    List<WPPosts> childPosts;
}
```

An example for the table could be (again: simplified!):

**id --- post_parent**
1 ---- null
2 ----    1
3    ---- 1
4    ---- null

So entity with id 1 should get a list childPosts of size 2 (containing post 2 and 3).

Unfortunately this does not work. I do not get any exception, but the list stays empty.

Comment: `mappedBy` is supposed to be referring to an *entity*, not an id. You need a `@ManyToOne WPPosts postParent` field for your mapping to work. Also note that with such a mapping, `WPPosts.postParent` is the owning side of the relationship, meaning that only changes to `WPPosts.postParent` will be honored by JPA; changes to `WPPosts.childPosts` will be ignored.

Comment: As far as accessing the list goes, you'll want to ensure to either only access the list within a transaction context, or declare the `@OneToMany` as `fetch=FetchType.EAGER`. Otherwise, you'll get lazy initialization exceptions

Comment: If you put your comment as an answer, I will approve it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mappedBy` is supposed to be referring to an *entity*, not an id. You need a `@ManyToOne WPPosts postParent` field for your mapping to work.

Note that with such a mapping, `WPPosts.postParent` is the owning side of the relationship, meaning that only changes to `WPPosts.postParent` will be honored by JPA; changes to `WPPosts.childPosts` will be ignored.

As far as accessing the list goes, you'll want to ensure to either only access the list within a transaction context, or declare the `@OneToMany` as `fetch=FetchType.EAGER`. Otherwise, you'll get lazy initialization exceptions.